# Is {force: true} the only way for invisible elements in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

Is there any alternative way apart from {force: true} on click & type function for the elements not visible in the web application using Cypress?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.should('be.visible')` like:

```
cy.get('#element-id').should('be.visible').click()
```

You can use `.wait()` like:

```
cy.get('#element-id').wait(2000).should('be.visible').click()
```

You can use `.then()` like;

```
cy.get('#element-id').then(($el) => {
    if ($el.is(':visible')) {
        $el.click()
    }
})
```